# Parse html table with BeautifulSoup4 and Python 3

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape certain financial data from Yahoo Finance. Specifically in this case, a single revenue number (type: double)

Here is my code:

```js
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  
searchurl = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s=AAPL"
f = urlopen(searchurl)
html = f.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

revenue = soup.find("div", {"class": "yfnc_tabledata1", "id":"yui_3_9_1_8_1456172462911_38"})
print (revenue)
```

The view source inspection from Chrome looks like this:
[image]

I am trying to scrape the "234.99B" number, strip the "B", and convert it to a decimal. There is something wrong with my 'soup.find' line, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locate the `td` element with `Revenue (ttm):` text and get the [next `td` sibling](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling):

```
revenue = soup.find("td", text="Revenue (ttm):").find_next_sibling("td").text
print(revenue)
```

Prints `234.99B`.